# ArcGIS runtime error "Polygon Geometry is null"

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I have created a Feature service using Point, Line, Polygon representation. I have used dataset that is provided by default in ESRI military Feature Template. I am using Advance feature symbology in ArcGIS Runtime, That feature service is working perfectly fine in ArcGIS Runtime in Offline mode. but when i added my custom representation in the area, it generated the error showing that "Geometry is Empty" while creating the feature layer in arcgis runtime. This error is only for polygons, custom added symbology is perfectly working fine in offline mode for point and line.

Environments:
ArcGIS Runtime API for Java 10.2
ArcGIS Server 10.4.1
ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1

Comment: What do you mean by "Offline mode" and how are you adding the feature service url in offline mode? Please share some of your Runtime Java source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by "Using Plus" button in ArcGIS Representation for custom representation rule but you can't use "load rule facility" of ArcGIS Representation to add saved rule from other representation data. If you added a new rule by loading rule that is saved from other representation. You will receive error that geometry is empty only for polygon case. I have solved my problem this way.